# Read the data from the csv file while keeping a watch on the folder for changes

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, dictionary

I have a code which keeps a watch on a folder for any alterations. It checks for newly added and removed files and promptly displays the name of the file when such cases happen. This is my code:

```
import os, time
import pandas as pd
import glob
path_to_watch = os.path.abspath('C:/Folder for violation csv/')
before = dict ([(f, None) for f in os.listdir (path_to_watch)])
while 1:
  time.sleep (2)
  after = dict ([(f, None) for f in os.listdir (path_to_watch)])
  added = [f for f in after if not f in before]
  removed = [f for f in before if not f in after]
  if added: print ("Added: ", ", ".join (added))
  if removed: print ("Removed: ", ", ".join (removed))
  before = after
```

Now I want to include one more thing in this code, I want to read the data in the file which is being added in the folder. I tried it by converting the dictionary into a DataFrame using `from_dict` and then using `pandas` to read the csv using `read_csv` but it doesn't seem to be working. This is my updated code:

```
import os, time
import pandas as pd
import glob
path_to_watch = os.path.abspath('C:/Folder for violation csv/')
before = dict ([(f, None) for f in os.listdir (path_to_watch)])
while 1:
  time.sleep (2)
  after = dict ([(f, None) for f in os.listdir (path_to_watch)])
  added = [f for f in after if not f in before]
  removed = [f for f in before if not f in after]
  if added: 
    print ("Added: ", ", ".join (added))
  df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(path_to_watch, orient = 'index')
  df1 = pd.read_csv(df)
  if removed: print ("Removed: ", ", ".join (removed))
  before = after
```

If you could help me get the desired result, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: why are you using from_dict?, I hope you need `df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path_to_watch, added))`

Comment: I tried using your code but I am getting the error: `TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'list'` .Sorry if this sounds like an amateur error, I am new to python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
import os, time
import pandas as pd
import glob
path_to_watch = os.path.abspath('C:/Folder for violation csv/')
before = dict ([(f, None) for f in os.listdir (path_to_watch)])
while 1:
  time.sleep (2)
  after = dict ([(f, None) for f in os.listdir (path_to_watch)])
  added = [f for f in after if not f in before]
  removed = [f for f in before if not f in after]
  if added: 
    print ("Added: ", ", ".join (added))
  for file_ in added:
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path_to_watch, file_))
  if removed: print ("Removed: ", ", ".join (removed))
  before = after
```

Answer (score 1):

- To begin with, it is better to use the **pathlib** package for accessing
  the file system.
- Use **set** to collect the file names.

```
from pathlib import Path

path_to_watch = Path('C:/Folder for violation csv/')
before = set(path_to_watch.glob('**/*'))
while 1:
  time.sleep (2)
  after = set(path_to_watch.glob('**/*')
  added = after - before
  removed = before - after
  for f in added:
     df = pd.read_csv(f)
  before = after
```

Comment: I don't know why but I am getting invalid syntax on `while 1:` line.

Comment: i missed a closing bracket. on the line before while. fixed it now.

Comment: Hi , @abhilb , I am getting this error now: `NotImplementedError: Non-relative patterns are unsupported`

Comment: i am not sure about the contents of the csv file? are you getting the error while reading the csv file? on which line is the error.

Comment: Yes, I am. You're right, this can be due to the content of csv file.

Comment: also i forgot to set before = after.. added that line now.

Comment: No problem @abhilb, Mohamed Thasin ah answer solved my problem. No worries. Thanks for the help :)